# Split data received into separate fields

Tags: php, mysql, curl

Problem : Data supplied is not ok for me to handle directly.

Description : I'm using curl to get data I need from another website.
However the data supplied on this website is formatted in a way that I need to split it to be able to work with it.

Example:

I'm scraping a div (soccer competition), but the match is supplied in one field, I need to have the 2 teams separated into 2 fields.

MysqlDB Field holds after the scrape:
`team 1 - team 2`

I need to separate that DB info into 2 columns

preg_match would be able to do this, but there are many opponents, so its a hassle like this.

Right now, I added (manually which is a pain) a team_id column and added myteam to the games which involve my team to the db table and did a where team_id = myteam
This way I can at least sort the competition table and just get my teams games.

This is the data I'm talking about getting with curl:

`$value['Wedstrijd'] = htmlentities($value['Wedstrijd'], ENT_QUOTES);`

So right now I'm scraping the field and putting it in the db.
I'm wondering, how can I separate the content of $value['Wedstrijd'] into 2 writes.....

Is this even possible?

I'm not able to post the entire code here, the formatting gets screwed.

Using substr and strrpos I was able to get the first team out the field,
I thought setting it to -1 would give me the other way around, which it actually does, but it doesn't go back till the - symbol, it just gives me 1 letter/symbol then.

`substr($wedstrijd,0,strrpos($wedstrijd,'-'));` this would return the first team, but I'm not sure how to use this to get the team after the - symbol.

Comment: Do you have any idea what you are asking? Without any examples and something you tried I doubt someone here will magically help you.

Comment: yes i do , i have everything working, im not asking for the entire scraping etc, im just asking how to seperate given info.

Comment: But try something first, show some code, anything. If I say that I have 2 bla bla's in my web bla bla and I'm trying to bla bla, how can I bla? Did you understood something?

Comment: hmm actually, you have a point, im sorry.

Comment: the data supplied looks like this in my DB right now : Team1 - Team2Post edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use strpos + substr or preg_match

Comment: THANK you very much, totally forgot preg_match, doh

Comment: I would if i was sure this was the best route to take.

Comment: So what i did was this 


$result=mysql_query($dbQuery);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$wedstrijd = $row["Wedstrijd"];
}
$arr = explode("-", $wedstrijd, 2);
$first = $arr[0];
$second = $arr[1];

This gives me arr0 and arr1 wich are the teams seperated.